# Pass value from controller to external library and then to View Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter and i am working on API Class, following is API Code

```
<?php
require_once("WiZiQService.php");
class ScheduleClass{

    function ScheduleClass($secretAcessKey,$access_key,$webServiceUrl)
    {
        require_once("AuthBase.php");
        $authBase = new AuthBase($secretAcessKey,$access_key);
        $method = "create";
        $requestParameters["signature"]=$authBase->GenerateSignature($method,$requestParameters);
        #for teacher account pass parameter 'presenter_email'
                //This is the unique email of the presenter that will identify the presenter in WizIQ. Make sure to add
                //this presenter email to your organization’s teacher account. ’ For more information visit at: (http://developer.wiziq.com/faqs)
        $requestParameters["presenter_email"]=$By_PresenterEmail;//"kerrygun@gmail.com";
        #for room based account pass parameters 'presenter_id', 'presenter_name'
        //$requestParameters["presenter_id"] = "40";
        //$requestParameters["presenter_name"] = "vinugeorge";  
        $requestParameters["start_time"] = $By_StartTime;//"2011-12-25 11:55";
        $requestParameters["title"]=$By_ClassTitle;//"my php-class"; //Required
        $requestParameters["duration"]=$By_ClassDuration; //optional
        $requestParameters["time_zone"]=$By_TimeZone; //optional
        $requestParameters["attendee_limit"]=$By_AttendeeLimit; //optional
        $requestParameters["control_category_id"]=$By_ControlCategory; //optional
        $requestParameters["create_recording"]=$By_CreateRecording; //optional
        $requestParameters["return_url"]=$By_ReturnUrl; //optional
        $requestParameters["status_ping_url"]=$By_StatusPingUrl; //optional
                $requestParameters["language_culture_name"]=$By_LanguageCulture;
        $httpRequest=new HttpRequest();
        try
        {
            $XMLReturn=$httpRequest->wiziq_do_post_request($webServiceUrl.'?method=create',http_build_query($requestParameters, '', '&')); 
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {   
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        if(!empty($XMLReturn))
        {
            try
            {
              $objDOM = new DOMDocument();
              $objDOM->loadXML($XMLReturn);

            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
              echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        $status=$objDOM->getElementsByTagName("rsp")->item(0);
        $attribNode = $status->getAttribute("status");
        if($attribNode=="ok")
        {
            $methodTag=$objDOM->getElementsByTagName("method");
            echo "method=".$method=$methodTag->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $class_idTag=$objDOM->getElementsByTagName("class_id");
            echo "<br>Class ID=".$class_id=$class_idTag->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $recording_urlTag=$objDOM->getElementsByTagName("recording_url");
            echo "<br>recording_url=".$recording_url=$recording_urlTag->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $presenter_emailTag=$objDOM->getElementsByTagName("presenter_email");
            echo "<br>presenter_email=".$presenter_email=$presenter_emailTag->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $presenter_urlTag=$objDOM->getElementsByTagName("presenter_url");
            echo "<br>presenter_url=".$presenter_url=$presenter_urlTag->item(0)->nodeValue;
        }
        else if($attribNode=="fail")
        {
            $error=$objDOM->getElementsByTagName("error")->item(0);
            echo "<br>errorcode=".$errorcode = $error->getAttribute("code");    
            echo "<br>errormsg=".$errormsg = $error->getAttribute("msg");   
        }
     }//end if  
   }//end function


}
?>
```

so my question is, how can i pass value from controller to attached external class and the output should be back to controller and then send it to view.

I'm trying to use it like this:

```
class Form extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->library('Create');
        $this->load->view('form_view');
    }
    public function wizprocess() {
        $this->load->library('Create');
        $this->Create->ScheduleClass();
    }
}
```

Your solutions to above question will be appreciated

Comment: This is basic usage of Codeigniter, so I must ask: What have you tried? I don't want to state the obvious answer if it's what you're already doing.

Comment: i didnt do anything so far, just waiting to hear solutions from experts so same i can start from scratch..

Comment: Sorry, we expect some basic effort on your part. If you haven't tried anything then I suggest that you do so and come back when you have a specific problem or concern.

Comment: I have tried creating function in controller and loaded external library...

Comment: Can we please see your controller code? The code you're having a problem with is what we need to see, it will make it very clear what your exact problem is.

Comment: what i want from you all, i would like to know how to use external library in controller with paramaters so i can start working on it..

Comment: I think I understand, I will post an answer.

Comment: <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Form extends CI_Controller {

 
 public function index()
 {
  $this->load->library('Create');
  $this->load->view('form_view');
 }
 public function wizprocess()
 {
  $this->load->library('Create');
  $this->Create->ScheduleClass();
 }
}

/* End of file form.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/form.php */

Comment: I just realized this is a function and not a class. Just include the file or add it to your autoload, and put it in `/helpers`. I have no idea what the "Create" class is, so I can't figure out what's the matter. Just realize that this is a global function definition, not part of a class, the way you have written it. Just include the file and call it: `ScheduleClass($secretAcessKey, $access_key, $webServiceUrl)`

Comment: I really like to see how to use codeignter to work with attached class file...if you can give me some idea how to start then i will do it my self..

Comment: Create Class is same which i have attached in this post...

Comment: Ah my mistake, the code formatting error was hiding it.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways to do it, the Codeigniter way:

```
$this->load->library('scheduleclass');
$this->scheduleclass->__construct($secretAcessKey, $access_key, $webServiceUrl);
```

I don't really like this, CI assumes your "libraries" constructors take one argument: an array of configuration. If you change your class to cooperate with this, you can load it like this:

```
$config = array(
    'secretAcessKey'    =>  $secretAcessKey,
    'access_key'        =>  $access_key,
    'webServiceUrl'     =>  $webServiceUrl
);
$this->load->library('scheduleclass', $config);
```

Then your class can [`extract($config)`](http://php.net/extract) or something to make sure the right variables are defined.

My suggestion would be just to use straight PHP:

```
// Either include the file somewhere or use an autoloader
include APPPATH.'third_party/ScheduleClass.php';
```

Then it's business as usual, except you aren't using CI's loader, just creating new objects with plain PHP.

```
// In your Controller
function mymethod()
{
    $class = new ScheduleClass($secretAcessKey, $access_key, $webServiceUrl);
    $this->load->view('myview', array(
        'ScheduleClass' =>  $class
    ));
}
```

One big problem is the poor design of your class, it only has one method (the constuctor) and it directly `echo`s everything rather than `return` a value, so the moment you create it - all the output will be sent to the browser.

Comment: Wesley!Thank You so much for this help, i wanted to know how to use $requestParameters["start_time"] = $By_StartTime;
$requestParameters["title"]=$By_ClassTitle; in your given function Mymethod() ????????????

Comment: You probably need to change the design of your class to `return  $requestParameters` so you can read them, or perhaps assign them to a class variable and read that instead. It's truly difficult to say what the best approach is since I don't fully understand what your requirements are.

Comment: so any advice to make class more easier plz

Comment: this is also part of "Create" class

Comment: My only advice is to keep trying, and if you really get stuck on something specific you can ask here after you've shown some effort and searched for the answer first. Understanding PHP would be more important than understanding Codeigniter, so focus on that.

Comment: This is how we call function from CreateClass.
`code`<?php
$access_key="AAAAAAAAa";
$secretAcessKey="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAa";
'
$webServiceUrl="http://domain.com/";
require_once("Create.php");
$obj=new ScheduleClass($secretAcessKey,$access_key,$webServiceUrl);